# Scale an image with Graphics2D

Tags: java, graphics, paint, graphics2d, paintcomponent

In a game that I am making I want the power ups to be airdrops. I have a image of a crate that I want to be draw bigger than I have drawn it. Then I want the image to become progressively smaller with times so that it looks like it's dropped from the air. I have crafted this code which I think should work but for some reason it doesn't.

```
if(power.getPowerUp()){
   double crateX = (int) power.getX();
   double crateY = (int) power.getY();
   Image crate = power.getCrate();
   int crateW = crate.getWidth(null) + 100;
   int crateH = crate.getHeight(null) + 100;
   if(crateW > 64){
      g2d.drawImage(
         power.getCrate(), (int) crateX, (int) crateY, crateW, crateH, this );
      crateX += .5;
      crateX += .5;
      crateW -= 1;
      crateH -= 1;
   }
   else {
      g2d.drawImage(
         power.getCrate(), (int) crateX, (int) crateY, crateW, crateH, this );
   }
}
```

I have this method inside `paintComponent(Graphics g)` and I use a Thread to repaint the graphics. Why doesn't it work? Does it have to do with something that I use values from another class? How would I make it so that the progressively smaller?

Answer (score 0):

You are recreating the `crateW` and `crateH` variables everytime the method is called. Then the method goes into either the if or else block, it never goes into the else (what you want) after having gone into the if block. In other words, the width and heights are the same next time the method is called.